# Tensorflow Training accuracy much higher than test accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am consistently getting around 60% accuracy for the training data but when I try and predict the outcome with my test data the model is about 50% accurate (which is to be expected if it were random).

```
def train_model(training_data, training_differential, test_data, 
test_differential):
    num_nodes = 180

    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(12, 22)),
        keras.layers.Dense(num_nodes, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
    ])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(training_data, training_differential, epochs=20)

predictions = model.predict(test_data)


return predictions
```

[image]

Not sure if I'm overfitting the data or if I'm using an incorrect model. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot things, what kind of data is going in and what are your target types? Are they classes like `[0,1]` or integers `[6,2]`. If they are classes then you probably don't need sparse categorical crossentropy just categorical crossentropy. If this is a binary classification problem e.g. `cat or dog` but never both then your final layer should be of size 1 where the target is a single vector where each value is either 1 or 0.

Also how big is your training set? If it's too small overfitting could well be a problem.

One place to start here regardless might be to reduce the number of nodes and thus the capacity of the network itself. You could also introduce some form regularization to prevent the network from overfitting on the training set.

Comment: I'm passing in arrays of integers, and it's a binary classification problem (it should be guessing only 0 or 1). My training set is about 800.

Comment: Okay, well in that case I would go about reshaping your target (y_train) to be a single vector of values something like `[0,1,0,1,1,0]` where each index i in y_train refers to the class of your inputs. The length of y_train should be the same as the length of x_train. In that case you will then need to use `binary_crossentropy` with activation set to `sigmoid` on the final layer. Your final layer should look like `keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")`